# Calculating cumulative values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate cumulative values. I tried the formulas below, none of them worked.

```
Cumulative_Forecast = CALCULATE(sum(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value]),
filter(ALLEXCEPT(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems,TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Year]), 
TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber]<=EARLIER(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber])))



Cumulative_Forecast2 = VAR RowDate = TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[Forecast_Date]
return CALCULATE(sum(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value]), 
FILTER(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems, TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[Forecast_Date]
<=RowDate && YEAR ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[Forecast_Date] ) = YEAR ( RowDate ))) 



Cumulative_Forecast3 = TOTALYTD(sum(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value]), 
'Calendar'[Date]) 



Cumulative_Forecast4 = CALCULATE(sum(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value]),
filter(ALL(DimDate[Date]), DimDate[Date] <= Max(DimDate[Date])) )
```

Here are some examples of records:

```
ForeCast_Value   Month   MonthNumber     ForeCast_BU     ForeCast_Year   ForeCast_ID
71100   Sep 9   Business1   2018    10648
71100   Oct 10  Business1   2018    10648
81000   Sep 9   Business1   2018    10649
71200   Sep 9   Business2   2018    10700
80500   Sep 9   Business2   2017    10500
80600   Oct 10  Business2   2017    10500
81100   Sep 9   Business2   2018    10650
```

I have a line chart; Month on the Axis, BU on the legend and value on values.

When slicer year is all selected

```
Business 1= 152100 and Business 2 =232800 on September 
Business 1= 71100 and Business 2 =80600 on October
```

When slicer year is 2017 selected

```
Business 2=80600 on Sep 
Business 2=80500 on Oct
```

I want to create a new line chart for cumulative values. Desired values are:
When slicer year is all selected

```
Business 1= 152100 and Business 2 =232800 on September 
Business 1= 223200 and Business 2 =313400 on October
```

When slicer year=2017 selected

```
Business 2=80600 on Sep 
Business 2=161100 on Oct
```

Answer (score 0):

The below DAX formulas can help you to get your expected results:

**Cumilative_Forecast = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value] ),
     FILTER(ALL(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems),TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_BU] =  max ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_BU] )) , FILTER(ALL(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems), TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber] =  max ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber] )),FILTER (
    ALL ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems ),
    TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Year] <=  max( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Year] ))

)**

The above formula gives result of 
" When slicer year is all selected

Business 1= 152100 and Business 2 =232800 on September 
Business 1= 71100 and Business 2 =80600 on October   "

**Cumulative_Value = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_Value] ),
     FILTER(ALL(TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems),TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_BU] =  max ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[ForeCast_BU] )) , FILTER (
    ALL ( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems ),
    TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber] <=  max( TEAMS_Forecast_LineItems[MonthNumber] ))

)**

The above formula gives result of 
"I want to create a new line chart for cumulative values. Desired values are:
When slicer year is all selected

Business 1= 152100 and Business 2 =232800 on September 
Business 1= 223200 and Business 2 =313400 on October   "

Please let me know does this reached your expected result or not.